# adding gradients to multiple items in a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, linear-gradients, css-gradients

How can I add a gradient class to multiple items back to back within this flex container while respecting the number of items? currently it only works by adding a class to one particular group of 'unit' and that produces separate gradients.

I'd like a gradient to cover two or more items while keeping all items flex and equal.

```css
     .chart {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
      }
      .dot-black {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: black;
      }

      .dot-grey {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: grey;
      }

      .dot-green {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: green;
      }

        .unit {
          flex: 1;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
         }

      .line-black {
       height: 2px;
       background: black;
        
      }

      .line-grey {
       height: 2px;
       background: grey;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }

      .gradient {
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
       }
```

```html
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="unit gradient">
        <div class="dot-black"></div>
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="unit gradient">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">

        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Currently working on a solution. JavaScript is hard sometimes, but I will post an answer soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the gradient on the parent element where you can specify the background size you want in order to cover only the needed elements:

```css
.chart {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1), rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1)) 
    left /* Start from the left */
    / 
    calc(var(--n,0)* 100%/8) 100%  /* we have 8 circles so Nx(width)/8 */
    content-box /* Cover only the content, don't account for padding */
    no-repeat; /* Don' repeat */
}

.dot-black {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: black;
}

.dot-grey {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background: grey;
}

.dot-green {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background: green;
}

.unit {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line-black {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}

.line-grey {
  height: 2px;
  background: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" style="--n:2">
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="dot-black"></div>
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">

    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chart" style="--n:5">
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="dot-black"></div>
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">

    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="chart" style="--n:6">
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="dot-black"></div>
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">

    <div class="line-grey"></div>
    <div class="dot-grey"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are intrested you can build the whole layout with only background and no html elements:

```css
.chart {
  margin: 0 15px 5px;
  height:22px;
  background: 
   /* Small dot */
   radial-gradient(circle 4px,black 95%,transparent 100%) left center/8px 8px no-repeat,
   /* horizontal line */
   linear-gradient(grey,grey) center/100% 2px  no-repeat,
   /* big dots */
   radial-gradient(circle 11px at calc(100% - 11px) 50% ,grey 95%,transparent 100%) left/calc(100%/8) 100%,
   /* Our Gradient */
   linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1), rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1)) left/calc(var(--n, 0)* 100%/8) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" ></div>
<div class="chart" style="--n:2"></div>
<div class="chart" style="--n:5"></div>
<div class="chart" style="--n:8"></div>
```

Comment: @woopsie the `--n:2` is a CSS variable that allow you to select the number of element and I use this variable to define the size of the gradient in the CSS

Comment: @woopsie I made some updates to make it clear, I also added another idea

Comment: is it a shorthand for something? where can I find documentation on it?

Comment: @woopsie it's a new feature, you can read about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: @woopsie it's called a *CSS variables*, it's a new feature of CSS. You can find the details in the link I shared

Comment: @woopsie here is some related questions using the same feature: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8620333+%5Bcss-variables%5D

Comment: @woopsie check the code of gradient, it's used there. I added an explanation of the logic

Comment: any idea how to do this for react native?

Comment: @woopsie react native doesn't support gradient or doesn't support CSS variable. I can easily remove the CSS variable and keep the gardient

Answer (score 1):

If the number of dots on that line is known and will never change, you can calculate the color stops yourself and implement them so that the line forms one full gradient.

However, if you want something to apply to anything like this, my suggestion is to **use Javascript.**

This function will calculate gradients for you. It's difficult, but it may be possible to implement it in an application so that it actually changes the CSS. I have manually done the calculations for the two units:

```js
//background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
function gradientProgress(gStart,gEnd,at){
  //gStart and gEnd are [r,g,b,a,%]
  var prog = (at - gStart[4]) / (gEnd[4] - gStart[4]);
  var res = [0,0,0,0,100]
  for(var a = 0;a<4;a++){
    res[a] = Math.round(gStart[a] + (prog * (gEnd[4] - gStart[4])));
  }
  return res;
}
console.log("First one: " + "[2, 0, 36, 1, 0], [9, 9, 121, 1, 70], [" + (gradientProgress([9,9,121,1,35],[0,212,255,1,100],50)).toString() + "]")
```

```css
.chart {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
      }
      .dot-black {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: black;
      }

      .dot-grey {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: grey;
      }

      .dot-green {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: green;
      }

        .unit {
          flex: 1;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
         }

      .line-black {
       height: 2px;
       background: black;
        
      }

      .line-grey {
       height: 2px;
       background: grey;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
```

```html
<div class="chart">
      <div class="unit gradient" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 70%, rgba(24,24,136,16) 100%);">
        <div class="dot-black"></div>
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="unit gradient" style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(24,24,136,16) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">
        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="unit">

        <div class="line-grey"></div>
        <div class="dot-grey"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```